# I am trying to reverse an array in C. But, the code throws out random 1-2 to some very large numbers digit numbers

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, reverse

As the title states I am trying to make a program using C which asks user to input the array creates a new array, where the values in the array have been reversed.
For ex,
Input: 10, 20, 30, 40
Output: 40, 30, 20, 10
I had written the following code for reversing the arrays,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100
int main()
{
    int sizeArray;
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int * ptr = arr;
    printf("Enter Array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &sizeArray);
    printf("Enter Array elements:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", ptr + i);
    }
    printf("Copying to another array....\n");
    
    int newArr[MAX_SIZE];
    int * ptr2 = newArr;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
    {
        *(ptr2 + i) = *(ptr + sizeArray - i+1 );
    }
    printf("Printing new array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", *(ptr2 + i));
    }
    return 0;
```

For ex:
When I input the values:
1, 2, 3, 4
The output is:
897546457,
1,
4,
3

Please help me with what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `ptr + sizeArray - i+1` the math seems wrong here, you either wanted to have `(i+1)` in parenthesis or `ptr + sizeArray - i - 1`

Comment: Don't write `*(foo + i)` but rather write `foo[i]`, it's more readable and it's the usual way it's done. Hint: if you get strange values when reading from an array, then the odds that you access the array out of bounds are very high. Start checking this. Also don't name your variables `ptr` and `ptr2`but give them meaningful names such as `original` and `inverted`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this statement

```
*(ptr2 + i) = *(ptr + sizeArray - i+1 );
```

the expression `ptr + sizeArray - i+1` points outside the set of actual data then `i` is equal to `0` or equal to `1` because in this case you have

```
ptr + sizeArray - 0 +1
```

that is the same as

```
ptr + sizeArray +1
```

and

```
ptr + sizeArray - 1 +1
```

that is the same as

```
ptr + sizeArray
```

Also you did not reset the pointer `ptr2` before this loop

```
printf("Printing new array:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", *(ptr2 + i));
}
```

If you want to use pointers to copy in the reverse order one array in another then the code can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main( void )
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int sizeArray;

    printf("Enter Array size: ");
    if ( scanf("%d", &sizeArray) != 1 )
    {
        sizeArray = 1; 
    }
    else if ( MAX_SIZE < sizeArray )
    {
        sizeArray = MAX_SIZE;
    }

    int *ptr = arr;

    printf("Enter Array elements:\n");
    for (; ptr < arr + sizeArray; ++ptr )
    {
        scanf("%d", ptr );
    }
    printf("Copying to another array....\n");
    
    int newArr[MAX_SIZE];
    int * ptr2 = newArr;
    
    while ( ptr != arr )
    {
        *ptr2++ = *--ptr;
    }

    printf("Printing new array:\n");
    for ( ptr2 = newArr; ptr2 < newArr + sizeArray; ++ptr2 )
    {
        printf("%d\n", *ptr2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You complicate your life with these pointers, they are not useful here. And use the [] operator for array access, it's easier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(void)
{
    int sizeArray=6;
    int arr[MAX_SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    printf("Copying to another array....\n");
    int newArr[MAX_SIZE];    
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = arr[sizeArray-i-1];
    }

    printf("Printing new array:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", newArr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even simpler/clearer -- make the copy loop `for (int i = 0, j = sizeArray-1; j >= 0; i++, j--) newArr[i] = arr[j];`